# Настроить общие папки в samba через sssd, который стучится в AD. В CentOS 7

Tags: centos, active-directory, samba, windows-server-2012, sssd

Есть файлопомойка на CentOS 7, есть Active Directory на Windows Server 2012. Сама CentOS введена в домен. С SSH проблем не возникло - он просто стал пускать доменных пользователей. Теперь хочется сделать так же легко с общими папками. Что прописать в `/etc/samba/smb.conf`? В сети есть километровые руководства по правке `krb5.conf`, но судя по всему - это всё равно что сейчас настраивать графику через `xorg.conf`.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/sssd-ad-integration.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось благодаря пинку [@alexanderbarakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/alexander-barakin) в нужную сторону. Итак:

Godmode:

```
sudo -i
```

Ставим нужные зависимости:

```
dnf -y install realmd sssd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir adcli samba-common samba-common-tools sssd-libwbclient samba
```

Вводим centos в домен с юзером `admin-of-ad` в домен `example.com`:

```
realm join -U admin-of-ad example.com
```

Правим `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```html
[global] 
    workgroup = example 
    security = ads 
    kerberos method = system keytab 
    realm = example.com 

[share] 
    comment = My shared folder 
    path = /data/share 
    public = yes 
    writeable = yes 
    browseable = yes 
    guest ok = yes 
    valid users = @"depit@example.com" 
    directory mask = 0775 
    create mask = 0664 
    vfs objects = acl_xattr 
    inherit permissions = yes 
    inherit acls = yes 
    map acl inherit = yes 
    store dos attributes = yes
```

Если шарится папка на ext*, то в параметры монтирования `/etc/fstab` надо дописать атрибуты `acl` и `user_xattr`. Должно хватить и `acl`, но мы же нанотехнологичные чуваки. Для `XFS` ничё не надо, всё «искоробки»:

```
UUID=dabdd229-52dc-49d6-add2-a10f9f582bf5   /   ext4    defaults,acl,user_xattr 0   0
```

Разрешаем полный доступ на уровне `ugo`. Локально всё равно только по ssh можно цепляться (ну только если у вас не проходной двор), а демон самбы сам разрулит кому можно, а кто идёт пасти бобров.

```
chmod 777 /data/share
```

Конкретно в CentOS самба после установки сама не запускается. И ей даже не разрешено это делать. Так что разрешаем запускаться:

```
systemctl enable smb.service
```

Разрешаем `firewalld` пускать самбу в сеть:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=samba
```

Применить правила без разрыва соединений:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

**ДАЛЬШЕ ОЧЕНЬ ХРЕНОВЫЙ И ГРЯЗНЫЙ ХАК**. Я ниасилил мандатное управление доступом, но записал себе в todo. Может потом допишу как надо.

Отрубаем `SELinux`:

```
sed -i 's/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled/' /etc/selinux/config
```

Перезагружаем весь сервер, просто потому что.

Источники: [раз](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/sssd-ad-integration.html), [два](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/496214-No-permission-to-access-Samba-share-from-windows), [три](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs).

Answer (score 2):

SELinux - как надо сделать
сделать валидным каталог дополнительный конфигураций /etc/samba/conf.share

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_secrets_t "/etc/samba/conf.share(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v /etc/samba/conf.share
```

сделать валидным каталог шары /mnt/recycle

```
semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/mnt/recycle(/.*)?"
restorecon -R -v /mnt/recycle
```