# Samba: нет доступа к папке

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, nas

Я развернул тестовый samba-сервер на CentOS 7 (с winbind и nmb соответственно). Удалил Firewalld, отключил selinux. На самба-сервере есть две условные директории: общая (public) и для определенных сотрудников (private) со входом по логину и паролю. Также у нас развернут сервер Active Directory (ADC-ROOT) и AD контроллер (ADC-001). В домен свой тестовый Самба сервер я ввёл, настроил Kerberos. На сервере Active Directory (ADC-ROOT) создал группу безопасности Test_NAS.test_group для своего сервера Самбы и добавил в группу свою доменную учётную запись Windows. По ip с компьютера захожу на файло-обменик и, если с общей папкой проблем нет, то папка приват не даёт доступ по доменным учётным данным Windows. В логах Самбы вижу ошибки вроде: nt_status_none_mapped или nt_status_access_denied, но решения, которые я нагуглил в интернете не решили проблему - меня всё также не "пускает" в папку приват. Также, в выводе tcpdump'а я увидел, что при попытке "залогиниться" в папку приват, пакеты доходят до AD контроллера (ADC-001), но не доходят до сервер Active Directory (ADC-ROOT) (хотя, все настройки ADC-ROOT реплицированны на ADC-001).

```
[global]
        netbios name = TEST_NAS
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        security = ADS
        realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL
        server string = test server
        map to guest = Bad User
        winbind use default domain = yes
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        log level = 1 vfs:2 winbind:2
        vfs objects = full_audit
        full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S|%U
        full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir pwrite
        full_audit:failure = none
        full_audit:facility = local7
        full_audit:priority = NOTICE


[private]
        comment = Folder for directors
        path = /samba/private
        read only = no
        guest ok = no
        browseable = yes
        force user = director
        force group = director
        directory mask = 0755
        create mask = 0644
        valid users = @"DOMAIN\\Test_NAS.test_group"
```

Comment: А как люди твой конфиг к себе будут копировать, чтобы воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Добавил конфиг в нужном виде

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657036/191416 может у меня что подсмотришь.

Comment: Спасибо, но я думаю, что Самба и весь сервер у меня настроены корректно, а проблема в AD и контроллере домена. Нужно на их стороне что-то прописать/добавить. Вопрос только что...

Comment: Ну подними виртуалку с моими настройками и посмотри будет ли работать у тебя. Я в тот период делал то же самое - нужно было для своего отдела бахнуть как раз закрытую папку как раз на центе и как раз с учётками в виндовом ad. На момент ответа - всё работало ровно так как было задумано.

Comment: А что ты делал на стороне AD?

Comment: Вообще ничего. Всё просто взяло и поехало.